# Convert list of typed numpy arrays to a 2d nump array or a 2d list?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a list containing **typed** (float32) numpy arrays:
`list = [array([ 0.02741675, -0.23331268, -0.04920139,  0.2501195 ], dtype=float32), array([ 0.1675, -0.268, -0.139,  0.195 ], dtype=float32)]`

I want to convert it into a 2d numpy array. something like:

`array([[ 0.02741675, -0.23331268, -0.04920139,  0.2501195 ],[ 0.1675, -0.268, -0.139,  0.195 ]], dtype=float32)`

I tried doing `numpy.array(list)`, like the answers to similar questions on this site suggest, but it doesn't change anything, *I suspect because the numpy array is typed*. How does one do this?

Comment: Applying numpy.array(list) might not be working as array might be checking for if the type is of numpy array, if so, don't do anything and return the parameter 'list'. This can be solved though through changing the dimensions of the array. Look into numpy dim, resize, ect for adding a second dimension to the array.

Comment: `numpy.array(list)` works on my machine

Comment: You have a list with one element on it. Grab the element (`list[0]`) and `reshape` with numpy (i.e. `list[0].reshape(-1,1)`)

Comment: can you give me more information about what you expect? Like a longer list, and longer output (not just 1)

Comment: what about [`np.vstack(list)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html)? Although `np.array(list)` on your example seems to work fine for me...

Answer (score 2):

`typing` has nothing do with it.  All numpy arrays have a `dtype`, even if the print display doesn't show it.

Recreating your list from the display:

```
In [428]: alist = [np.array([ 0.02741675, -0.23331268, -0.04920139,  0.2501195 ]), np.array([ 0.1675, -0.268,
     ...:  -0.139,  0.195 ])]                                                                                
In [429]: alist                                                                                              
Out[429]: 
[array([ 0.02741675, -0.23331268, -0.04920139,  0.2501195 ]),
 array([ 0.1675, -0.268 , -0.139 ,  0.195 ])]
```

As several comments indicate, `np.array` applied to the list creates a 2d array:

```
In [430]: np.array(alist)                                                                                    
Out[430]: 
array([[ 0.02741675, -0.23331268, -0.04920139,  0.2501195 ],
       [ 0.1675    , -0.268     , -0.139     ,  0.195     ]])
```

`np.stack` does the same.

```
In [431]: np.stack(alist)                                                                                    
Out[431]: 
array([[ 0.02741675, -0.23331268, -0.04920139,  0.2501195 ],
       [ 0.1675    , -0.268     , -0.139     ,  0.195     ]])
```

Sometimes people start with an object dtype array of arrays.  In that case the `stack` works when `np.array` does not.

But if the arrays in the list differ in shape, then neither will work.

```
In [432]: alist = [np.array([ 0.02741675, -0.23331268, -0.04920139,  0.2501195 ]), np.array([ 0.1675, -0.268,
     ...:  -0.139])]          # remove an element                                                                               
In [433]: np.array(alist)                                                                                    
Out[433]: 
array([array([ 0.02741675, -0.23331268, -0.04920139,  0.2501195 ]),
       array([ 0.1675, -0.268 , -0.139 ])], dtype=object)
In [434]: np.stack(alist)                                                                                    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-434-724d9c1d0554> in <module>
----> 1 np.stack(alist)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py in stack(arrays, axis, out)
    414     shapes = {arr.shape for arr in arrays}
    415     if len(shapes) != 1:
--> 416         raise ValueError('all input arrays must have the same shape')
    417 
    418     result_ndim = arrays[0].ndim + 1

ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape
```